# Add Symbol in RichEditBox List UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, richeditbox

I would like to use other symbols for the lists of the richeditbox, in addition to the only symbol present that is the "bullet", is possible?

For example the symbols in the fontfamily Wingdings.

Below the code to create the list with the "bullet" circle.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid Width="700" Height="800">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="BtnBullet" Width="32" Height="32" Content="B" Click="BtnBullet_Click" Margin="5"/>
    </VariableSizedWrapGrid>
    <RichEditBox x:Name="RebText" Grid.Row="1" KeyDown="RebText_KeyDown"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void BtnBullet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.UI.Text.ITextSelection SelectedText = RebText.Document.Selection;
    ITextParagraphFormat ParagraphFormatting = SelectedText.ParagraphFormat;

    ParagraphFormatting.ListType = MarkerType.Bullet;
    SelectedText.ParagraphFormat = ParagraphFormatting;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `RichEditBox` does not provide such api to custom `ParagraphFormatting`. You could only use [`MarkerType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.markertype) existing enumeration. If you do want another symbol, please feel free to ask for this feature on [**UserVoice**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=pin%20secondary%20tile%20without%20user%20consent).

Comment: Thank you..! I will try to ask on user voice

Comment: hi @Ticras, If you have asked, please share the voice link below

Comment: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/37001662-pin-secondary-tile-without-user-consent